# Autocomplete from inside Module and SetDelayed

Tags: autocomplete

Autocomplete in Mathematica 9 offers suggestions from inside SetDelayed and Module. For example, after running:

```
func[thing1_, thing2_] := thing1 + thing2;
Module[{thing3},
 thing3 = 10;
 thing3 + 4
]
```

autocomplete will offer `thing1`, `thing2`, and `thing3` as suggestions. Since they are intended to be local, this gets in the way. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I doubt there is... `Autocomplete` will offer all symbols in the `Global` context and just using it in a `Module` creates a persistent symbol (even if its value is cleared).

Comment: @rm-rf sounds like an answer...